# Adding a computed column based on the criteria in another column(s)

Tags: r, aggregate, calculated-columns

I'm new to R and looking at ways to sum a column when the other column(s) has corresponding row entries.

I'm working on this (simplified) [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS2Js.png). It has 78 rows in total.

I used the following function

`group_by(type_of_pastry, allergen) %>% dplyr::summarize(n = n())`

to generate [this table summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoCYf.png)

The next task is to populate the latest column, 'Total' with the sum of value in 'Volume' column based on the type of pastry. For example, lines 1 and 2 (Croissant) should therefore show a value of 43 and respectively, 35 for line 3 and 4 (Cheese brioche).

Having spent time searching for solutions, most of them directed me towards `aggregate`, which would alter the structure of the dataset whilst the goal is to maintain the structure as above. Any guidance would be very appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which however removes the other columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(type_of_pastry) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(count))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  type_of_pastry Total
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Cheese brioche    35
2 Croissant         43
```

or this, which preserves the other columns (but duplicates the `Total`):

```
df %>%
  group_by(type_of_pastry) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(count))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   type_of_pastry [2]
  type_of_pastry allergen count Total
  <chr>          <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Croissant      Nut         23    43
2 Croissant      None        20    43
3 Cheese brioche Nut         18    35
4 Cheese brioche Milk        17    35
```

or this, which gives you everything in compact form:

**EDIT 1**:

```
df %>%
  group_by(type_of_pastry) %>%
  summarise(
    Total = sum(count),
    allergen = str_c(allergen, collapse = ", "),
    count = str_c(count, collapse = ", "))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  type_of_pastry Total allergen  count 
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     <chr> 
1 Cheese brioche    35 Nut, Milk 18, 17
2 Croissant         43 Nut, None 23, 20
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
df %>%
  #group_by(type_of_pastry) %>%
  summarise(
    Total = sum(count),
    allergen = str_c(allergen, collapse = ", "),
    count = str_c(count, collapse = ", ")
   )
  Total             allergen          count
1    78 Nut, None, Nut, Milk 23, 20, 18, 17
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. I'm looking for the second one. However, the fourth column (Total) would just end up adding all the numbers in 'count' column, generating 78 across rows instead of showing what you have up there

Comment: Please check EDIT 2 - that's what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I found a way, really appreciate your help

Comment: Which (alternative) way did you find? And if my answer helped you in anyway, consider showing your appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Here is `dplyr` solution using `count`:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  count(type_of_pastry, allergen, name="count") %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(count), .by=type_of_pastry)

 type_of_pastry allergen count Total
1 Cheese brioche     None     1     5
2 Cheese brioche      Nut     4     5
3      Croissant     None     4     6
4      Croissant      Nut     2     6
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(order = c("C-23232", "D-35253", "F-43953", "D-48205", 
"D-12659", "C-82645", "A-58344", "F-83759", "C-73213", "A-98732", 
"F-42842"), type_of_pastry = c("Croissant", "Croissant", "Cheese brioche", 
"Cheese brioche", "Croissant", "Croissant", "Croissant", "Cheese brioche", 
"Cheese brioche", "Cheese brioche", "Croissant"), allergen = c("Nut", 
"None", "Nut", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Nut", "Nut", 
"Nut", "Nut")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```